# start AsyncTask the second time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin

i'm building an android app that counts the time since one of the activity started, the first time i started the activity everything works fine the timer works fine and it display the time on the TextView.
When i finish the activity(flipping the phone),and try to start again the timer works fine(i display it as a Log) but the textview doesn't change

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Activity): String? {
    val acc = Accelerometer(params[0])
    dealsList.forEach {Log.d("fallDeals", it) }
    while (true) {
        sleep(100)
        publishProgress()




        Log.i("TAG", "${tiltSensorsValues[0] - acc.xPos!!} ${tiltSensorsValues[1] - acc.yPos!!} ${acc.zPos!!}")
        if (flippedPhone(acc)) {
            Log.i("REFRENCES", "${dbRefrences.stateRef}")
            dbRefrences.stateRef.setValue("empty")
            addToOldDataTableDatabase()
            return "Triggered"
            break

        }
    }
}

private fun flippedPhone(acc: Accelerometer) =
        (tiltSensorsValues[0] - acc.xPos!! < -4 || tiltSensorsValues[0] - acc.xPos!! > 4 ||
                tiltSensorsValues[1] - acc.yPos!! < -4 || tiltSensorsValues[1] - acc.yPos!! > 4)


override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    dbRefrences.currentRef.child(USERS).removeValue()
    dbRefrences.stateRef.setValue("empty")
    Toast.makeText(context,setTimer(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}


//*********************************************
//Functions
//*********************************************

/**
 *  adding the data to the old data table
 */
private fun addToOldDataTableDatabase() {
    val oldDataTableRef = dbRefrences.tableRef.child(OLD_DATA)
    oldDataTableRef.child(gDate()).child(getCurrentTime())?.child(TIME)?.setValue(timer.text)
    Log.i("My Service", userList.size.toString())
    userList.forEach {
        oldDataTableRef.child(gDate()).child(getCurrentTime())?.child(PARTICIPANTS)?.
                child(it.userId)?.setValue(it.name)
    }

}

private fun gDate(): String {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
    return df.format(c.time)
}


/**
 * return the time that has passed since the group started
 */
private fun setTimer(): String {
    val difference = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - startTime
    val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(difference).rem(60)
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(difference).rem(60)
    val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(difference).rem(24)

    Log.i("TAG", "${String.format("%02d", hours)}:${String.format("%02d", minutes)}:${String.format("%02d", seconds)}")
    return "${String.format("%02d", hours)}:${String.format("%02d", minutes)}:${String.format("%02d", seconds)}"
}

/**
 * changing the textView text to the time that has passed since they started
 */
override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Void?) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
    timer.text = setTimer()


}
```

by the way i'm using kotlin

Comment: AsyncTask holds the reference of your activity and whenever you recreate your activity your old one still there because of AsyncTask and old AsynctTask still running, that is why you can see log. All this code is example of how you should'nt code.

Comment: `When i finish the activity(flipping the phone),and try to start again`. It is unclear what you try to start again.  Moreover asynctasks cannot be restarted. You should create a new asynctask.

Comment: My god ... @Bernouilli Gate can you stop editing every post? Pretty annoing. I was checking what OP had edited to only discover that it was you again.

Comment: so what i should do instead @Viktor Yakunin ?

Comment: @greenapps  for Simplification i have two activity, one, have a button to go to the other activity and the second activity start the AsyncTask and count the time, when i flip the phone the second activity finish(cancel the AsyncTask) and i'm returning to the first activity,but when i try to start the second activity again it doesn't work

Comment: That makes no sense. If you flip the phone during second activity the second activity restarts. You do not have to do anything for that. And it will not go back to first activity first.

Answer (score 0):

Simple timer application to solve your problem could be implemented this way:

```
class TimerApp : Application() {//TODO add TimerApp to manifest
    val startTime: Long by lazy { System.currentTimeMillis() }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: TimerApp
            private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

}

class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //init your views
        val timerTV = TextView(this)
        timerTV.postDelayed({ timerTV.text = TimerApp.instance.startTime.getElapsed() }, 1000)
    }
}

fun Long.getElapsed(): String {
    val delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - this //elapsed time in ms
    TODO("return formatted string")
}
```